# how to find Vertices that share many connections to other Vertices

Tags: gremlin

I am new on gremlin api and I would like to ask for an interesting use case.

I have a graph that looks like the following

```
(Article1)-[refers_to]->(Company1)<-[refers_to]-(Article2) 
(Article1)-[refers_to]->(Person1)<-[refers_to]-(Article2)
(Article1)-[refers_to]->(Person2)<-[refers_to]-(Article2) 
..
(Article1)-[refers_to]->(Company1)<-[refers_to]-(Article3)
..
```

My Goal is to identify the vertices of type "Article" that have more than X vertices in common with another vertex of type "Article1".

Regarding the previous example:
- I would obtain {Article1,Article2} as a tuple that has more than 2 (3 in this case) common index
- I would exclude {Article1, Article3} cause this tuple shares only 1 common vertex.

Any suggestion for this task?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `Article1`/`Article2` are `ids` of vertices, `refers_to` is the `label` of edge:

```
g.V('Article1').as('source').out('refers_to').as('middle_v').in('refers_to').where(neq('source')).as('target').select('middle_v', 'target').groupCount().by(select('target')).unfold().where(select(values).is(gt(2)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is an interesting solution.